# Underperforming participants (<50% accuracy) in LMM

Tags: glmm, data-preprocessing

I have to perform a linear mixed model analysis on behavioural conflict paradigm data (ie analysis of congruency effects) and I'm struggling to find reliable sources on what to do with respect to underperforming participants (ie those with <50% accuracy in the task). In repeated measures/mixed ANOVA analyses I typically remove them as analyses are performed on correct trials and thus they present a lot of missing data (and biased congruency effects), but I don't know whether LMM inherently handles this and therefore their exclusion is not justified.

Comment: Have you used a random intercept and slope for each participant?

Comment: I'm using random intercepts for each participant, but I cannot add slopes because it's a complex model and it doesn't converge then.

Comment: So what issues do you have with LMM?

Comment: I have three within-subjects factors (2 levels each) plus one between-subjects factor (3 levels) and, therefore, many possible random slopes I could add to the model (and that could be interesting to look at from a theoretical point of view). However, I have been able to simplify the model in a way that makes sense (and works). My issue at the moment is a more basic one: whether to include or not those participants whose accuracy falls below chance, as I'm unsure the model can account for this variable if I don't remove them from the dataset.

Comment: This is tough, you cannot just exclude as you have figured out. You should probably find out why they are underperforming. Can these participants be grouped in any way? Do they share some similarities?

Comment: Low rates of underperformance are common in the types of tasks I'm assessing and they seem to be quite random - or, at least, there are no obvious apparent patterns. I can try to see if my model supports it as a factor (coded underperformance YES / NO)?

Comment: Adding an additional variable that would differentiate the underperforming participants is probably the easiest option. That way you will analyze them separately.

Comment: Yes, I'll try that. Thank so much for your advice!